# Bundle 'org.eclipse.wb.core.java' , org.eclipse.jdt.core and org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core cannot be resolved in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm redoing a legacy code from a plugin for eclipse ide, but I'm having problems with the following imported libraries:

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IPackageFragment;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaModelException;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment;
```

The error message reported in the Ide and the following:

```
The import org.eclipse.jdt.core cannot be resolved
The import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core cannot be resolved
```

I also have a problem with the following import in the MANIFEST.MF file.

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.wb.core.java;bundle-version="1.5.2"
```

The error message reported in the Ide and the following:

```
Bundle 'org.eclipse.wb.core.java' cannot be resolved
```

I wonder if I need to install some dependency or if the path changed.

Edit 1 The complete MANIFEST.MF.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ModuloAnalysis
Bundle-SymbolicName: ModuloAnalysis; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: moduloanalysis.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core,
 org.eclipse.wb.core.java;bundle-version="1.5.2"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/smellplatform.jar,
 .,
 lib/weka.jar
Import-Package: org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.debug.core,
 org.eclipse.debug.core.model,
 org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core,
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.actions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `org.eclipse.jdt.core.xxx` imports require you to add the `org.eclipse.jdt.core` plugin to the `Require-Bundle` list in the MANIFEST.MF

`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment` is also in `org.eclipse.jdt.core` however this is an **internal** class so the code is breaking the rules by using it.

I think `org.eclipse.wb` is WindowBuilder - do you have that in your target platform?

Comment: Yes, I have the WindowBuilder installed but the continuous error

Comment: Even with org.eclipse.jdt.core in the  Require-Bundle, the eclipse still does not recognize imports

Comment: You might need to do a 'Source > Organize Imports' on the files doing the imports to get them to pick up the changes. Also what version of the wb plugin is installed?

Comment: Using a version 1.9.0.

After arranging imports solve the problem of some but not all of them, some examples of those that still give error are the import: 
   org.eclipse.jdt.core.IPackageFragment;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.PackageFragment;

Comment: Resolved all imports pertaining to org.eclipse.jdt but continue with the same problem for org.eclipse.ui.IMarkerResolution; and org.eclipse.ui.IMarkerResolutionGenerator; The path org.eclipse.ui is already in MANIFEST.MF.

Comment: Those are in `org.eclipse.ui.ide`

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: In the Require-Bundle, it is just another plugin you depend on

Comment: It is no longer giving the error of import but at the time of implementing the class, informs: IMarkerResolution can not be solved to a type